# How to set the Theme programatically in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I got situation like I am using multiple themes in my php website and also integrate a wordpress blog.

For example this is my site URL: `http://example.com`

There I want to switch Themes by passing a query parameter like:

```
http://example.com?mytheme=red_theme
http://example.com?mytheme=blue_theme
etc.
```

Currently my activated theme in WordPress is like `blue_theme` and my WordPress blog URL is like:

```
http://example.com/blog?mytheme=red_theme
```

e.g.: `red_theme` should be display just like preview.

Otherwise if I go through this URL:

```
http://example.com/blog
```

Then the default theme (`blue_theme`) should be display.

I can adjust it in core PHP but i don't know how to do it with WordPress.

Comment: [`switch_theme()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme)...

Comment: Have you already looked for existing plugins here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/theme-switcher ?

Comment: Hi mevius, thank you for advise this wordpress function and I also tried out using that function and it works fine but this function is activate theme permanently I am looking for it should keep the theme temporary based on query string url. otherwise the default theme is activated previously...

Comment: @PriyankKhunt Maybe you can store the current/default theme name, then when a user accesses with a URL that doesn't contain a theme, reset to the one you have stored somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

In WORDPRESS, you can set Theme Programmatically, Based on Device, like different theme on mobile and different theme on Desktop. Write below code in functions.php of your Default theme

```
function use_mobile_theme() {
    // Chech device is mobile or not
    if(wp_is_mobile()){
        return 'theme19388'; // set theme name here, which you want to open on mobile
    }
    else {
        return 'milano'; // set theme name here, which you want to open on other devices, like desktop
    }
}

add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'use_mobile_theme' );
add_filter( 'template', 'use_mobile_theme' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to change the WordPress theme programmatically.

```
function my_custom_theme() {
    return 'your-theme-name'; //replace your theme name
}
add_filter( 'template', 'my_custom_theme' );
add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'my_custom_theme' );
```